# One of the thread functions not executing possible race condition

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, race-condition

```
std::condition_variable waitforme;
std::mutex block;
std::atomic<bool>check = false;

void cpu_show_answer(std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<std::string>& v2) {
    while (check == false) {
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
        if (v1[i] != NULL) {
            cout << "Found your word: " << v2[v1[i]] << " at index " << v1[i] + 1 << endl;
        }
    }
}
void cpu_parallel_search(const int begin, const int end, std::string search_term, std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<std::string>& v2) {
    for (int i = begin; i < end && check==false; i++) {
        if (search_term == v2[i]) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(block);
            v1.push_back(i);
            check=true;

        }
    }   
}

 main(){
    int threads=0;
    cout << " THREADS: ";
    std::cin >> threads;
    int begin = 0;
    int finish = (words.size() / threads) - 1;
    std::string search_term = "";
    while (search_term == "") {
        cout << "Please enter the word you want to find: ";
        std::cin >> search_term;
    }
    the_amp_clock::time_point start1 = the_amp_clock::now();
    std::vector<std::thread> myt;

    for (int x = 0; x < threads; x++) {
        myt.emplace_back(cpu_parallel_search, begin, finish, search_term, looking, words);
        begin = begin + words.size() / threads;
        finish = finish + words.size() / threads;
    }
    cpu_show_answer(looking, words);                
    for (auto& x : myt) {
        x.join();
    }

    the_amp_clock::time_point end1 = the_amp_clock::now();
    auto time_taken1 = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end1 - start1).count();
    cout << "Finding the word took " << time_taken1 << " ms. Using a parallel cpu search.\n" << endl;
}
```

Hi so my program searches through a vector of words and sees if there is a match if there is a match then I have found the word and want to show the user that I have their word and tell them the index in the list where the word has been found. My problem is that the cpu_show_answer() function never actually runs the bit of code where it displays the word and the index (the for loop in cpu_show_answer). The reason it doesnt run the code is that even if I have found the word the vector cointaining the found words size is always zero within the cpu_show_answer function. I dont know why that is.

Comment: Where do you declare `words`? What is the size? What is `the_amp_clock`? What is `looking`? Please most a [mcve].

Comment: Also have you tried to put a print where you set `check=true;`? or even better a break point? do you get to that part of the code?

Comment: If the word's not found you'll run forever. If more than one thread finds it you have a race condition since the `cpu_show_answer` doesn't use the mutex to read the vector.

Answer (score -2):

Hi so the reason this was failing was that the size of v1 in the cpu_show_answer was not being passed correctly or rather it wasnt being updated so to fix it I changed the thread function calls to

```
myt.emplace_back(cpu_parallel_search, begin, finish, search_term, std::ref(looking), std::ref(words));
```